# How do they make icons from little boxes with numbers and characters in them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Just out of curiosity, how does this works?

```
content: "";
```

Above CSS code becomes a heart icon on Medium. Is it purely CSS or some JavaScript involved? Or what are these called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an unicode character, like  or ❤.
Check [this unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/es/) and try.

You have some useful information about unicode at [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Make sure that either your current font-family supports the characters or that one of the fall-backs does. Depending on browser and system fonts for the user, the outcome may vary with some of the more obscure / unsupported characters